# Method still running after compiler reads it

Tags: java

Hi based on my tutorial I have tried an interesting exercise (at least for me).

My main class looks like below

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main (String[]args){       
        Link link = new Link();
        link.interfaceListener(new LinkerInterface(){
            @Override        
            public void showNumber(int numb) {
                System.out.println(numb);
            }
        });   

        link.calc();
    }
}
```

My Link class looks like below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Link {
    private boolean trueFalse;    
    private LinkerInterface interface1;    
    int numb;

    public Link() {    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
        numb = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        try {    
            Thread.sleep(5000);    
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {    
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

        if (numb == 1) {    
            trueFalse = true;    
        }
        else if (numb == 0) {    
            trueFalse = false;    
        }
    }


    public void interfaceListener(LinkerInterface interface1) {    
        this.interface1 = interface1;    
    }


    public void calc() {    
        if (numb == 0) {    
            interface1.showNumber(0);    
        } else if (numb == 1) {    
            interface1.showNumber(1);    
        }    
      }
    }
```

My only interface is as below

```
public interface LinkerInterface {
    public void showNumber(int numb);
}
```

I put int thread.sleep just to provide me enough time to compute input into the scanner before the link.calc() is triggered.

My question is, basically when I input 1 for example into scanner, compiler would have already read

```
link.interfaceListener(new LinkerInterface(){   
            @Override    
            public void showNumber(int numb) {    
                System.out.println(numb);
            }
        });
```

in my main method. So how is this code above being called back when link.calc() is initiated? why is compiler going back to read it? shouldn't it be giving some non pointer exception or something like that when it realized that my calc method in Link class was pointing interface1.showNumber(0); which practically does not have anything to execute? What is making it reference back to my main method?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indention of you Java code. It is unreadable. Please also remove all those blank lines.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with executing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of execution is this:

1. you create a new `Link` object
2. code inside the `Link` constructor is called, users enters a number, thread sleeps, etc..
3. you create a new `LinkerInterface` instance which implements the `showNumber` method, but it **isn't called** at *this* point
4. you call `link.calc();` method, which in turn calls the `interface1.showNumber(...)` method

If you'd set the `LinkerInterface` *after* calling `calc`, you'd get `NullPointerException` (i.e. switching step 3. and 4.).

> I put int thread.sleep just to provide me enough time to compute input
>   into the scanner before the link.calc() is triggered.

Not true, `scanner` *waits* for user's input. `sleep` is useless here, it will always sleep 5 seconds, regardless of how long it took user to enter the number...

Oh yeah, and compiler doesn't *execute* your code. JVM does. Compiler just translates your java code into byte code which is used by JVM.

Comment: Yes but I want to know why. Why is it that calling 'calc' initiate 'LinkerInterface' ? 'LinkerInterface' is set up in main method but what makes the parameter of 'calc' to be passed onto the main LinkerInterface? sorry I'm a real noob and u can see that but I have nowhere else to ask

Comment: @forJ I've edited my answer to be more detailed

Comment: So only way of doing this is by using interface right?

Comment: Setting up a parameter for a method that is not in the same class?